# C programm opens SDL window successfully but doesn't printf

Tags: c, sdl

I copied a quick SDL example into my IDE but the program ignores any other commands I write like printf();

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SDL.h"
#include <MCSControl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Surface *surface;
    SDL_Event event;
    printf("Test");

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Couldn't initialize SDL: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return 3;
    }

    if (SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(320, 240, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE, &window, &renderer)) {
        SDL_LogError(SDL_LOG_CATEGORY_APPLICATION, "Couldn't create window and renderer: %s", SDL_GetError());
        return 3;
    }

    while (1) {
        SDL_PollEvent(&event);
        if (event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
            break;
        }
        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    }
    printf("test");


    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);

    SDL_Quit();

    printf("Test");

    return 0;
}
```

This program does not print any of the things I told it. to but it opens a window successfully.
Does anybody know why?

edit: when I am building the project this are the build messages:

```
====================[ Build | FullBuild.13.2.24.2 | Debug ]=====================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" --build C:\Users\sbraun\CLionProjects\FullBuild.13.2.24.2\cmake-build-debug --target FullBuild.13.2.24.2 -j 18
[1/2] Building C object CMakeFiles/FullBuild.13.2.24.2.dir/main.c.obj
[2/2] Linking C executable FullBuild.13.2.24.2.exe
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libgdi32.a when searching for -lgdi32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libgdi32.a when searching for -lgdi32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libwinspool.a when searching for -lwinspool
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libwinspool.a when searching for -lwinspool
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libole32.a when searching for -lole32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libole32.a when searching for -lole32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/liboleaut32.a when searching for -loleaut32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\liboleaut32.a when searching for -loleaut32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libuuid.a when searching for -luuid
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libuuid.a when searching for -luuid
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libcomdlg32.a when searching for -lcomdlg32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libcomdlg32.a when searching for -lcomdlg32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libgdi32.a when searching for -lgdi32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libgdi32.a when searching for -lgdi32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libcomdlg32.a when searching for -lcomdlg32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libcomdlg32.a when searching for -lcomdlg32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libiconv.dll.a when searching for -liconv
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.3.3\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/MinGW/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32

Build finished
```

not sure if the skipping of all the stuff is important

Comment: Did you pass `-mwindows` to the linker to hide the console?

Comment: do you mean in Cmake? NO

Comment: Maybe SDL makes CMake do it implicitly. Rebuild in verbose mode and look at the linker flags.

Comment: I would need a more detailed description of how I could do that. Am still a beginner

Comment: I don't know how to make Clion do it. When building from command like (`cmake --build ...`), adding `--verbose` should print the commands.

Comment: You could also write on a file instead of printing on the console. If you write on a file, and the file is written after program execution then you'll know your instructions are all executed

Comment: Add newlines `/n` to your strings.

Answer (score 0):

SDL doesn't print the usual printf functions in the console. Instead one needs to use SDL_Log(). same syntax as printf.